# Raspberry pi shows 32bit architecture but has 8GB ram

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

When I run the commadn `lshw` on my pi I get:

```
raspberrypi                 
    description: ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
    product: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
    serial: 10000000c21d2792
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smp
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1500MHz
          capacity: 1500MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 cpufreq
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@1
          size: 1500MHz
          capacity: 1500MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 cpufreq
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@2
          size: 1500MHz
          capacity: 1500MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 cpufreq
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@3
          size: 1500MHz
          capacity: 1500MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 cpufreq
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 5
          size: 7875MiB
     *-pci
          description: PCI bridge
          product: Broadcom Limited
          vendor: Broadcom Limited
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 10
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:65 memory:600000000-6000fffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller
             vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
             physical id: 0
             bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:66 memory:600000000-600000fff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.10.11-v7l+ xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.10
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: USB2.0 Hub
                   vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 4.21
                   capabilities: usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: USB Keyboard
                      vendor: SEMICO
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@1:1.1
                      version: 1.10
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=2Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: USB Receiver
                      vendor: Logitech
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:1.4
                      version: 24.11
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.10.11-v7l+ xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.10
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: dc:a6:32:b9:0a:3e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.10.11-v7l+ link=no multicast=yes port=MII
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: dc:a6:32:b9:0a:3f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.229 firmware=01-2dbd9d2e ip=10.0.0.4 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:37:a5:06:02
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

I thought 32bit architecture supports only 4GB of RAM. How is it showing 32bits but has 8GB RAM? Unless the Pi I have is not actually 32bit?

The version of my pi is `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4`

Comment: 64bit raspberry pi OS is still beta stage - so, yes, it's 32bit - though, with the right config, you can run a 64 bit kernel

Comment: The fact that 32bit only supports 4GB of RAM is actually a windows thing stemming from DOS and the early Intel x86 Architecture of processors,

Comment: Also If you  `PAE` enabled you can use up to 64Gb of Ram for more info look here: https://www.linuxlookup.com/howto/use_more_4gb_memory_ubuntu_linux_32_bit

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit) can use 8GiB through physical address extensions (PAE) even though it has a 32 bit user space.

The kernel can see and use all 8GiB, although any given process on the system is limited to 4GiB.

The Pi4 uses kernel7l for BCM2711 which supports Large Physical Address Extension (LPAE) and 8GiB RAM.

Comment: kernel7l does not support 64 bit. It is the kernel8.